# Access localStorage variable data in other controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, local-storage, ng-storage

Under the controller named `usersConrtoller.js` I'm storing some object data in the `localStorage` using `ngStorage`.

```
$scope.users = [{
        "entity$": "-/sys/daily_journeys",
        "name": "Tom",
        "walked": 90,
        "traveled_distance": "773",
        "total_cout": 0.367,
        "days": 22,
        "avg_risk": "0.0",
        "risk_category": "GREEN"
}]
```

saved to local storage:

```
$localStorage.users = $scope.users;
```

How can I access `$localStorage.users` object's data in other controllers?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the `ngStorage` is an injectable service so in other controller you just need to inject the service and read it

```
$scope.users = $localStorage.users
```

or you might need to watch over it to see if it's updated

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
  return $localStorage.users
}, function (users) {
  $scope.users = users;
})
```